# How can I use a global function inside an object in modular design

Tags: jquery

How can I use an object returned by the global `pagination` function inside `loadMore`. Currently it says undefined. What's the correct way of assigning pagination value into a variable?

```
var test = (function($) {
    //global function
    function pagination(opt, limit){
        if (typeof opt === 'object') {
            var data = opt;
            //data['limitstart'] = 2;  
            var list = { data: data }
            list.data[0]['limitstart'] = limit;
            list.data[0]['sweep'] = 0;
            $('[data-load-more]').show();
            return list.data;
        }
    }

    return {
        loadMore: function(){
            var test = pagination();
            console.debug(test);//undefined
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: You didn't pass any variables to `pagination()` -- do you get an error?

Comment: @LambdaNinja, no error, but test = undefined. I hope the list.data returned by pagination too be usable here within loadMore

Comment: That's because you don't return anything when `opt` is not provided to `pagination()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, ok noted...